# How do I retrieve a specific object in a jquery array to do jquery with it?

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have a simple set of images nested in a div tag, I'm just wondering how I can chose an item with a specific index programatically?

```
var n = new Array();
n.push(a);
n.push(b);
n.push(c);

n[1]; // b
```

How do I do this in JQuery?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`:eq(index)` selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) or the [`.eq(index)` function](http://api.jquery.com/eq/), like this:

```
$("#myDiv img:eq(0)")  //get the first one
//equal to: $("#myDiv img").eq(0)
$("#myDiv img:eq(1)") //get the second one
//equal to: $("#myDiv img").eq(1)
```

Alternatively, there's [`.get(index)`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) if you want the actual DOM element and not the jQuery (wrapped) element, like this:

```
$("#myDiv img").get(0)  //get the first one
```

All of the above options have a **zero-based** index.

Answer (score 0):

```
var image = $('#div_id img').get(2)
```

Comment: Thanks, did use this originally but I couldn't call any methods, I'll review my syntax when I have a moment.

e.g. I couldn't do 
var image = $('#div_id img').get(2)
image.show();

Comment: @Chris yeah - as Nick alluded to this will return the dom element only and will not have access to jQueries chaining methods.